Best way to install three 36" x 80" frameless mirrors onto wall
I am looking to put 3 large and heavy mirrors onto one of the walls in my room and am looking for advice on several things. I put in a mirror rack on top of the baseboard and nailed it to the studs and drywall, and will put the hooks on top of the mirror. Will I also need to put adhesive or will the rack be enough? Also, what would be the best way to lift and put on the mirrors to not risk it bowing and breaking? I tried to see if there were anything online on the installation process but the mirrors shown are usually smaller and easier to carry.

What's "a mirror rack"? What weight is it claimed to carry? FYI, nails aren't usually used in things like this. Screws are much more reliable.

@isherwood OP probably means a J-mold mirror mount.  (With you on screws>nails.)

Speculation doesn't help. I'm not sure why people drag me back here all the time for that when I post clarifying questions. We need facts and details from the OP.

The best way to lift a large sheet of glass is with a person on each end, carefully, each with one hand at a side to stabilize and another at the bottom to lift.
The best way to do it solo, if you really must, depends on the situation -- its size, your strength, where you are moving it from and to, whether you have to hold it in place while installing/removing mounting hardware.

Suction cups (the ones designed for the job) can be very good are giving you a solid hold on the stuff.

@Ecnerwal: Very true. I've mostly used those for lifting raised-floor panels rather than glass, so I forget about 'em. And mostly I've been too cheap to invest in them. Though it might be worth checking rentals and/or "library of things" if your town has one.

We install this size mirror or maybe a tad bigger for a lot of double vanities. There are really only two methods of installing them... for us:

You install a rail (you can find kits and cut to size) or use the backsplash as the rail.   From there you install mirror and then a second rail at the top (to keep it from moving outward).   So the install steps are install rail, move mirror over, hit mirror with a few dabs - maybe 6-8 small dabs -  of silicone or glue (whatever we have open), press it on wall above rail, and then install second rail at the top.  I personally like this install because we can move the mirror out without breaking.

Sit it on something - backsplash, counter, shelf, whatever... and then smear the crap out of it with mirror glue and press it in.   Make sure to tape it to wall until glue is dry.


As for moving it... For something that size you need three people.   One for each side and one in the middle who holds the middle but mainly a guide and watching for it to tip over.   As comments in the other answer suggest you can use suction cups.   I would advise against it unless you are used to them.   Suction cups are for very heavy things like granite, large stone wall slabs and things that are heavy and hard.   Mirrors are thin and in my opinion too much flex to use suction cups - although if someone is using them everyday I can definitely see the speed advantage.

Okay, I successfully did it! It was easier than I thought, it just needed to be done slowly and carefully, installing and focusing on one part of the wall and mirror at a time. (Sorry in advance if I go too into detail it's a habit). I sanded down 8 circles spread out onto the wall per each mirror (I don't plan on taking them off) and then dabbed on liquid nail adhesion onto the sanded parts. I put 2 suction cup handles (80 pound max ones) onto the middle of the mirror because in my head (I know I'm strange) it lessened the tension of the middle of the mirror. Me and my mom carried them on each end horizontally into the room and then re adjusted the cups to be aligned in the same direction the mirror was laying and then from its side lifted the mirror so that it was standing upright. We got it close to the wall before lifting it onto the jay channel (the rail thing we nailed above the baseboard to the studs) and then pushed it so that it stuck to the glue. From there my mom pushed and held it and I got on a ladder and nailed hooks on top where the studs are. I put 3 hooks onto the first one and 4 on the other two (where there weren't studs I put in those plastic caps and nailed in the hooks through it). Repeat the whole process for the other mirrors. Now I plan on putting a frame on the edges so it doesn't look bald but otherwise I'm done. The only thing I messed up on is not poking holes in my sander or covering my things because now my room is covered with dust oopsies. But thank you to those that responded, it helped give me an idea for what to do :)

